JetPack Compose show the update states in the UI in the right way
i am trying to update the task and i am listening to three states

Loading
Success
Error
None

the the state that i am using in the view model like this
sealed class UpdateTodoListState() {
    object None : UpdateTodoListState()
    object Loading : UpdateTodoListState()
    object Success : UpdateTodoListState()
    data class Error(val errors: List<String>?) : UpdateTodoListState()
}

in the View Model i am using _updateTodoListState to hold the loading data from server
private var _updateTodoListState: MutableStateFlow<UpdateTodoListState> =
        MutableStateFlow(UpdateTodoListState.None)
    val updateTodoListState = _updateTodoListState.asStateFlow()

private fun updateTask(taskId: Int, updateTaskRequest: UpdateTaskRequest) = onIO {
        tasksRepository.updateTask(taskId, updateTaskRequest).onStart {
            _updateTodoListState.value = UpdateTodoListState.Loading
        }.catch {
            _updateTodoListState.value = UpdateTodoListState.Error(it.parseServerError())
        }.collect {
            _todoListState.value =
                TodoListState.Success((todoListState.value as TodoListState.Success).response.filter { e -> e.id != taskId })
            _updateTodoListState.value = UpdateTodoListState.Success
        }
    }

In compose i am listen to state like this
val updateTodoListState by remember(todoViewModel) {
        todoViewModel.updateTodoListState
    }.collectAsState()

and handle the cases like this so when i got the spesifc state app show toast or loading
when (updateTodoListState) {
        is UpdateTodoListState.Loading -> {
            LoadingDialog(
                onDismissRequest = {
                    todoViewModel.resetTodoListUpdate()
                })

        }

        is UpdateTodoListState.Success -> {

            Toast.makeText(
                LocalContext.current,
                "Task marked as done $markedIndex",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            todoViewModel.resetTodoListUpdate()

        }


TodoListState.Error -> {
            Toast.makeText(LocalContext.current, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            todoViewModel.resetTodoListUpdate()
        }

        else -> {}
    }

i am using this method to reset the UpdateTodoListState by markig it as none so for the next recomposition the state will be none so the app will not do any thing
fun resetTodoListUpdate() {
        _updateTodoListState.value = UpdateTodoListState.None
    }

if the screen make recomposition the latest state from updateTodoListState is observed because updateTodoListState hold the latest state so to solve this issue i call the function resetTodoListUpdate() can you please recommend better way to listen to UpdateTodoListState only when its changed not every recomposition

Ok so a couple of things here to collect the state you don't need to remember it and pass the view model as a key. You should just collect the state
val updateTodoListState by todoViewModel.updateTodoListState.collectAsState()

Also you should not be updating in the composition the state.
So _updateTodoListState is a MutableSharedFlow and you will only collect here to inform the user with a toast or a dialog you should use LaunchedEffect for that and for the loading dialog add it into the view.
val context = LocalContext.current
val updateTodoListState by todoViewModel.updateTodoListState.collectAsState()

//Watch for the side effects of this state
LaunchedEffect(updateTodoListState){
  when(updateTodoListState) {
    is UpdateTodoListState.Success -> {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Task marked as done $markedIndex", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    is UpdateTodoListState.Error -> {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Ups! an error happened! :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    else -> {}
  }
}


//Check is it is loading
if(updateTodoListState is UpdateTodoListState.Loading) {
  LoadingDialog(
    onDismissRequest = { todoViewModel.resetTodoListUpdate() }
  }
}

//The rest of the view

